# Can't update android 4.4 to 4.4.2 on nexus 7 2012

Tags: updates, nexus-7, ota-update, rom-update

I have a rooted nexus 7 running android KitKat 4.4.
On my notification bar there is an update message to make o.s 4.4.2 , when I click on it to install the update, it restarts the tablet and the screen says installing the update, after 2 minutes the screen says the message "install error" and it forces me to restart the device.

The o.s doesn't update and notification stays on top.

I installed twrp and through that I tried updating the device but that didn't work either.

Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: What exactly does the error message say. If you've rooted you may have installed an app which has modified a system file. When installing an update it verifies the current system and won't install if anything has been changed. The error message will likely tell you what file has been modified. Replacing that file with an unmodified version should allow you to install the update. The other option is to flash the factory image.

Comment: It says error install!

Comment: Can you add a screenshot/photo of the screen showing the message? It will almost certainly say what file caused it to error.

Comment: Have a feeling, that 1) you're rooted and 2) boot loader is unlocked, you may have to revert to stock boot & recovery and re-load stock 4.3 **AND** important bit, *re-lock the bootloader*. After that, the OTA upgrade should then proceed, then look for Nexus Root Toolkit (NRT) to do the job for you. *You will lose everything!*